# Disable all customer related routes

Tags: magento2, customer, routing

I'm building a Magento 2.2 store and would like to remove all customer pages like login, account, register, etc.

I noticed that I can remove all customer routes (customer/ * / *) when I remove the /vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/frontend/routes.xml file but of course that's not a neat way, do you guys have an idea on how this could be achieved in a neat way?

Thanks!

Comment: you can create observer and redirect all this route in specific page like home page so user are not able to access that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the `controller_action_predispatch` observer and made a list of routes that other users can't access, if the requested route is found in my list, the user gets redirected to the not found page.